# How to create design of comment and reply on comment like facebook comments in ios

Tags: ios, tableview

I want to create a comment and reply design like facebook.
How to render replies dynamically to Comments table view cell.

Comment: follow this: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: @MAhipalSingh  Can you be more specific? I checked that library, but that creates a single view controller that loads the chats, so how can I create a comment view like facebook comments? Thank you